# Failed to upload apk to google play

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I just got the following error report when attempting to upload my lastest version of an already published app:

```
 Upload failed

Your APK cannot be analysed using 'aapt dump badging'. Error output:

Failed to run aapt dump badging:
W/ResourceType(12572): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020095 (t=1 e=149) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType(12572): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020095 (t=1 e=149) in package 0 (error -75)
W/ResourceType(12572): Failure getting entry for 0x7f020095 (t=1 e=149) in package 0 (error -75)
ERROR getting 'android:icon' attribute: attribute is not a string value
```

Even if you don't know the full explanation, I'm still interested in any possible clues. For example what is a resourcetype 12572? and what is "dump badging"? and what could a failure to get entry mean?

**EDIT:** In answer to some comments...

I did change the name of the icon file in this most recent version (this could be a clue). The manifest now contains (amongst a ton of other stuff...):

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/mygameapp_icon"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

I also have the text in my app in english and Korean. This is arranged by having the english strings in a file called strings.xml in a directory called res/values and a set of Korean strings in a file called strings.xml in a directory called res/values-ko

Comment: apparently your icon is wrong. can you post your manifest and comment on the icon part ?

Comment: Does your app use Localization?

Comment: I will make edits to OP...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question...

I just noticed that I have different sized mygameapp_icon.png files in drawable-xlarge, drawable-large, drawable-normal, drawable-small, but not in plain old "drawable". Putting a new icon in drawable made my problem disappear.

Though now I'm confused, when might the icon in plain "drawable" be used? what if its a completely unsuitable size for that device?... or should I have written something different to `android:icon="@drawable/mygameapp_icon"` ? somethink akin to `android:icon="@drawable/some_kind_of_wildcard/mygameapp_icon"` ??